Laravel email verification URL redirect to 404
I want to use a custom template for verification emails being sent by Laravel 11. It generates a verification url, but when I click it, it shows 404 on the browser.
Below is my user model where I generate the URL and pass to my custom notification class:
public function verificationUrl()
    {
        $user = $this;

        $hash = urlencode(Hash::make($user->email));

        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify',
            now()->addMinutes(config('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            ['id' => $user->getKey(), 'hash' => $hash]
        );
       
    }

public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl();
        $this->notify(new \App\Notifications\VerifyEmail($verificationUrl));
    }

I am getting the email with a URL like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/verify/17/%242y%2412%24pYgHVLqVp49BRu%2FyA40Me.CmogjO17sMc2IG06VuKQj4gnElWSBTu?expires=1717544173&signature=16ad181c7b8f733077d4de1dda24e6d65663223bb4ab36608e51f63cda74328e

This is my web.php route:
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'verify'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])
    ->name('verification.verify');

This is my controller:
public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard'); // or any other route you want to redirect if already verified
        }

        if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
        }

        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('verified', true);
    }

I am looking for some help to find out where I have gone wrong. The default url being generated works with $request->fulfill();.

I have posted my answer.Please check.

Though you have successfully generated URL using signed URLs method and your route defination is correct, You didn't correctly mapped the route with the verify method of EmailVerificationController.
you need to pass the route parameters after the Request $request instance of the verify method even though you don't need those parameters for the code . The correct method signature given below
public function verify(Request $request,$id,$hash)
{
 .........
 .........
 .........
}

Try this. I think it will work.
For more information on Laravel Route you can check the official docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#route-parameters.
